# Windows 10: Manually configure one wireless network and leave the rest on auto

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

My primary network connection for a Windows 10 box is a wireless connection to an Android phone. Unfortunately, the phone's wireless tethering is buggy, and often the DHCP lease is incorrect, causing me to be unable to open any new network connections. The specific issue is that the phone doesn't hand out a gateway.

My proposed solution to this is to configure the network manually, avoiding DHCP altogether, as every attempt to flash a new ROM on the phone has failed. Which brings me to my question:

**How can I set manual IP settings for *just one* wireless network?**

By setting the IPv4 settings on the network adapter, it appears that it applies to *all* wireless APs, and not just the one I want to configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way of setting the IPv4 settings for a specific network only as opposed to a specific adapter, but I would suggest another approach for you particular situation.

Windows allows you to set an Alternate Configuration for when no DHCP server is found. By default it is set to automatically give you an address in the `169.254.0.1` through `169.254.255.254` range when no DHCP server is found. You can change this default to specifc IPv4 settings of your choosing; in your case, your phone's wireless configuration. To do so, do the following:

1. Go to **Network and Sharing Center**
2. Go to **Change Adapter Settings**
3. Right-click your Wireless Adapter
4. Choose **Properties**
5. Select **IPv4 Properties**
6. In the **General** tab choose **Obtain an IP address automatically**
7. Now up top choose the **Alternate Configuration** tab
8. By default you'll se the Automatic private IP address radio button selected. This is what sets it to the default `169.254.x.x` range. Instead select the **User configured** radio button. Now enter your phone wifi IP information
9. Click OK and you're done.

So if you're on any other network with DHCP it will connect automatically with no problem, but will switch over to manual settings when you start having DHCP lease issues on your phone's wifi network.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's idiotic that Windows doesn't have the ability to make per-SSID settings, but I suspect you're right. I've set things up as you suggested. So far, DHCP is working so I can't test it.

Answer (score -1):

I realize this was asked over a year ago, but...In Windows 10 go to All Settings then Network and Internet then select Wi-Fi on the left hand side. Select Manage known networks. select your phones Wi-Fi (I assume its saved since its already been connected to in the past) and click Properties. Scroll down to IP settings and click Edit. Change the drop down to Manual. Turn on IPv4 or 6 (whatever your flavor) and enter all the pertinent info. Boom, Static IP per wireless network.